# replace special characters of html

Tags: java

I need to parse a html file and convert the character 'à' into

`'&agrave;'`

My input file is:

```
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body>
   à  
 </body>
</html>
```

My java code is:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(content);
content=content.replace("à","&agrave;");
System.out.println(content);
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This code prints:

```
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body>
   à  
 </body>
</html>
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body>
   &agrave;  
 </body>
</html>
```

I overwrite the input file but it remains the same of beginning.
How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'm flagging as "unclear" because it is ambiguous as to what you mean by "it remains the same of beginning." The file is, indeed, changed by the replacement that you have (of course, you should use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`).  Thus, the input file does not "remain the same."

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

for html5 use this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```